# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $\sigma_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${a_n}$ be any sequence of numbers converging to $0$, and let $\sigma_n$ be the sequence of arithmetic means (averages),

$\sigma_n= \frac{a_1 +a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $\sigma_n = 0$

The answer states the following:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ so that $|a_n|<\epsilon$ when $n \ge N$. Then, write

(1) $|\sigma_n| \le \frac{|a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_N|}{n} + \frac{(n-N)\epsilon}{n}$

(2) and from this, get $\lim$ $\sup |\sigma_n| \leq \epsilon$. Since this holds for any $\epsilon>0$, $\lim \sigma_n = 0$

First off, I don't see how we're able to get to (1). I see that $(n-N)$ is positive, but I don't see how we're able to derive (1). Then, how do we get from (1) to (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For the first term, fixed N, the numerator is fixed, while the denominator $\to \infty$ so this term $\to 0$.  The second term is $\lt \epsilon$ for all n, since $\frac{n-N}{n}\lt 1$.

2) Statement (1) gives limsup$_{n\to \infty}|\sigma_n| \le \epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, the limit is $0$

Answer (score 2):

For (1), note that
$$
|a_{N+1}+\cdots+a_n|\leqslant |a_{N+1}|+\cdots+|a_n|\leqslant 
\underbrace{\epsilon+\cdots+\epsilon}_{(n-N)\ \  \text{terms}}\leqslant(n-N)\epsilon
$$
by the choice of $N$.

For (2), note that for fixed $N$, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_1+\cdots+a_N|}{n}=0,\tag{3}
$$
since the numerator in the fraction is a fixed real number; also
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-N)\epsilon}{n}=\epsilon.\tag{4}
$$

The point of the argument is that for every given $\epsilon>0$, you *fix* the positive integer $N$ and then consider the consequence as $n\to\infty$.

Consequently, by (1), (3) and (4), we have for every $\epsilon>0$
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\sigma_n|\leqslant 0+\epsilon=\epsilon,\tag{5}
$$
and thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\sigma_n|=0$, which implies the desired limit.

Note that we use $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$ in (5) since we haven't establish the existence of the limit of the sequence $\{|\sigma_n|\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What (1) is actually doing is splitting $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ up into two kinds of elements:

1. Elements in a tail of the sequence ($a_{N+1}, a_{N+2},\ldots$) which we know are close to $0$ (within $\epsilon$), and
2. The elements that occur before that tail ($a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N$).

All that (1) does is estimate the tail: there are $n-N$ elements between $a_{N+1}$ and $a_n$, and each is at most $\epsilon$ in absolute value.  The initial elements $a_1,\ldots, a_N$ are left intact.

As for going from (1) to (2), all that is happening is to note that in the first sum, the set of elements never changes but the denominator tends to infinity; and the second is always smaller than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

Shown:

1) $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\sigma_n|= 0$.

2) We still need to show that

$\lim \inf_{ n \rightarrow \infty} |\sigma_n|=0$.

Since

$0 \le \lim \inf_{ n \rightarrow \infty}|\sigma_n| \le $

$\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\sigma_n| \le \epsilon$,

we have

$\lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\sigma_n| =$

$\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\sigma_n| =0$,

$\Rightarrow$   $\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} |\sigma_n|=0$.

Used:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=a \iff$

$\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n= \lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=a.$